# Get Collection of items by pipe separated GUIDs in sitecore

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7.2

Basically I used multi-list in rendering parameter for an category selection. so i got pipe separated GUIDs of selected item & needs to get a collection of items, is there any method supported by Sitecore api instead of iterating in loop. that could be expensive in terms of efficiency as compare to any built-in Sitecore method.

Answer (score 8):

There is a MultilistField class in Sitecore.Data.Fields, used as follows

```
var mlf = new MultilistField(item.Fields["field name"]).
mlf.GetItems();
```

I don't think it's any more efficient than what you're already doing though. In fact, it probably does just the same internally.

Answer (score 6):

Another way, avoiding a potential ArgumentNullException (in the case of `item.Fields["field name"]` being null) is to use `Sitecore.Data.ID.ParseArray` in combination with a linq statement to get a list of items as follows:

```
var items = ID.ParseArray(item["field name"])
               .Select(id => item.Database.GetItem(id)).ToList();
```

Comment: Good point. In fact, this is the way I prefer to do it, and rarely use `MultilistField`. I was just giving the official answer :)